# Why sometimes I cannot edit Logic Apps properties in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-logic-apps

I want to open Logic Apps in VS2017 with the plugin "Azure Logic Apps for Visual Studio 2017". When I open the Logic App designer in VS, a window "Logic App Properties" shows and asks me to select a subscription and then ressource group.
When I chose the correct subscription, most of the time all dropdown are disabled and I cannot open my logic App. However, sometimes it's working normally and I can open my Logic App.

Do you have any idea of what is causing that and how consistently open Logic App in designer?

Answer (score 0):

When you open your logic app project in the Logic Apps Designer, you might not get the option for selecting your Azure subscription.  This behavior happens because after you open a logic app's .json file, Visual Studio caches the subscription for future use. To resolve this problem, try one of these steps:

- Rename the logic app's .json file. The subscription cache depends on
  the file name.
- To remove previously selected subscriptions for all logic apps in
  your solution, delete the hidden Visual Studio settings folder (.vs) 
  in your solution's directory. This location stores your subscription 
  information.